# asp.net core 2.0 preview package restore failure

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0

Getting the below error while installing any NuGet packages

Using VS 2017 with ASP.NET core 2.0 preview

> Install-Package : Version conflict detected for
>   Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common.   image-resize-web-app (>= 1.0.0) ->
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.All (>= 2.0.0-preview2-final) ->
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor (>= 2.0.0-preview2-final) -> 
>   Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp (>= 2.3.0-beta1) ->
>   Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common (>= 2.3.0-beta1)   image-resize-web-app
>   (>= 1.0.0) -> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design (>=
>   2.0.0-preview1-final) ->  Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc (>=
>   2.0.0-preview1-final) -> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration (>= 2.0.0-preview1-final) ->  Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.EntityFrameworkCore (>=
>   2.0.0-preview1-final) -> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Core (>= 
>   2.0.0-preview1-final) -> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Templating (>=
>   2.0.0-preview1-final) ->  Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Utils (>=
>   2.0.0-preview1-final) -> Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces (>= 2.0.0) ->  Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces.Common (>= 2.0.0) -> Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common (>= 2.0.0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

image-resize-web-app (>= 1.0.0) has a dependency on Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common (>= 2.3.0-beta1) which conflicts with Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common (>= 2.0.0) through another dependency chain.

You might be able to solve it by upgrading or downgrading to a version which has all dependencies satisfied.